# Run Code on Click Button or Update Field, but Not Both at the Same Time

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want both:

- `<input onchange='fncChkVrification()'>`
- `<button onmouseup='fncChkVrification()'>Hit Enter after pasting or typing the Code. Or Click Here.</button>`

For ease of use, I want the user to be able to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after an input text box is filled in, and have code run.  The problem is, that the user may need to come back to that input field later, and re-run the code with the same value.

### For example:

- User enters a verification code in the input field and hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
- But they haven't signed in.  So the user gets a message stating that they haven't signed in.
- They sign in, and come back to the input field to run the verification, but when they tab out of the field or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, no code runs because the verification code is the same.

The code only runs if the value changes. I'm assuming that the browser records and tracks the value and whether it's been changed.

I could:

- clear that field if there is an error, and make the user enter the verification code *again*. But I'd like to avoid that.
- Only use a button, and not the `onchange` event.

I want to give the user *both* options.  I've read that JavaScript will not simultaneously run two functions at the same time, but if the code is very short, and runs very quickly, will it get run twice, not simultaneously, but immediately in sequence?

If for some reason the code runs a second time, it might not affect the outcome at all, but I'd like to avoid unnecessary duplication.

The code **DOES** run twice!  If I click the button, both events trigger.  The `onmouseup` from the button, *and* the `onchange` from the input field.

```
window.countTimesRun = 0;

window.fncChkVrification = function() {
  console.log('fncChkVrification ran: ');
  
  countTimesRun = countTimesRun + 1;
  console.log('countTimesRun: ' + countTimesRun);
  
  var getVrfyChkCode = document.getElementById('divForOnHoldKey').value;
  
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(rtrnFromVerify)
    .verifyCode(getVrfyChkCode);
};
```

Technically, JavaScript might not be running simultaneously, but the code is so short, and so quick that it's running twice, back to back.

I could somehow pause, or track, or keep a timer.  But that just seems like way to much overkill to make it worth it.  I may need to just have a button, and no `onchange` event.  Unless someone has a simple solution.  I'm not using jQuery.

If JavaScript had an `onexit` event for an input field, that would probably solve the problem.   But as far as I know, that doesn't exist.

I thought maybe changing the button `onmouseup` event to `onclick` might do something, but that doesn't work.

I just tried using `onblur` and that created a lot of very undesirable situations.  The code runs when the field looses the focus, but then the cursor stayed in the input field.  So it got stuck in a loop if I clicked on a new browser tab.  The code would run, the new browser tab would NOT load, and then the focus went right back to the same place!

I experimented with the button getting the focus, but when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the cursor does not move to the next tab element.  If I click <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the button gets the focus, and the code runs.  But if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens.

I've come to realize, that the solution to my problem is by controlling what happens when the user hits the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  So, in a sense, this is a duplicate question to making code run when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.  Which I didn't realize at the time I posted this.

I found a solution.  The key to the solution is they `keyCode` check.  Here is a working jsFiddle:  [Run Code on Either Enter Key Press, or Button Click, but not Both](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/mc7dq/)

Comment: you could add a flag to your event to signal when an instance is running and sets to false when its execution ends

Comment: Yes, I though of something like that.  Reset a true/false value at the very end of the code logic.  For that, I'd need to either declare a global variable, and store something in cache.  Which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have gotten yourself in a muddle here. If I have understood correctly this fiddle does what you are describing: http://jsfiddle.net/wR32h/

This is the meat of it:

```
FormManager.prototype.initialize = function () {
    this.elements.input.onkeyup = this.handleInputKeyup.bind(this);
    this.elements.button.onclick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
};

FormManager.prototype.handleInputKeyup = function (evt) {
    // check to see if the key was enter
    if (evt.keyCode !== 13) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.checkState()) {
        this.validateCode();
    } else {
        alert('you need to log in before validation can take place');
    }
};

FormManager.prototype.handleButtonClick = function (evt) {
    if (this.checkState()) {
        this.validateCode();
    } else {
        alert('you need to log in before validation can take place');
    }
};
```

We can eliminate any problems which occur as a result of blur and change events by capturing the onkeyup and simply returning out if the key wasn't enter.

With this approach you shouldn't have multiple events firing etc... It is hard to see what exactly is going wrong without more of your code but hopefully I have understood correctly and covered your question.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle that basically does what I want.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/mc7dq/)  I did end up using the keyCode check.

Comment: So did you solve the problem? It's worth noting that removing your event attachment from the HTML is a worthwhile thing to do.